# VSCode eslint error in IDE but not in CLI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint

I have absolute imports in VScode that builds fine and runs fine with eslint in CLI but not in VSCode.

In the image below is the error in vscode and the output of the linter.

[image: vscode error]
[image: linter ok]

I also have a `jsconfig.json` file with the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["*"],
      "components/*": ["components/*"],
      "redux/*": ["redux/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Any ideas on how to make VSCode resolve the import and therefore have Intellisense work ?

Comment: You are not alone, may be this will be helpfull
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14907

Comment: Pretty strange, I just checked on my machine, your config works fine for me and produce no error. VsCode 1.24.0, Node 7.9.0

Comment: @Vitalii yes already checked that but did not fix the issue unfortunately :-(

Answer (score 0):

If `components`, `pages`, and `redux` are your local folders, then try adding `./` as a prefix to them.

```js
import {Header} from './components';
import {Home} from './pages';
```

This informs linters that we are looing for a relative import and not from `node_modules`

Comment: OP has the `baseUrl` configured in his/her `jsconfig.json`. There shouldn't be any problems with absolute paths